Elasticsearch date in range date_histogram extended_bounds
I want to get date_histogram during specific period, how to restrict the date period? how should I use the extended_bounds parameter? For example : I want to query the date_histogram between '2024-07-10' and '2024-07-22', and the fixed_interval could be changed. I query with this expression insuring having the same filter range in the query:
GET /logging-events/_search
{
    "size": 1,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gt": "2024-07-10T00:00:00",
                            "lt": "2024-07-22T23:59:59"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "date_ranges": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "fixed_interval": "8d",
                "extended_bounds": {
                    "min": "2024-07-10",
                    "max": "2024-07-22"
                },
                "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
        }
    }
}

But I still get the date_histogram not in the range.
Unexpected Response :
aggregations.date_ranges.buckets[0].key_as_string eq 2024-07-08
{
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 13,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "max_score": 0.0,
        "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "logging-events",
                "_id": "BuP86ZAB2uzWuz8xZdkz",
                "_score": 0.0,
                "_source": {
                    "_class": "com.ecommerce.monitoring.services.event.LoggingEvent",
                    "event_type": "CLICK",
                    "session_id": "b2f4d3a1-4d4e-4f67-9b2a-0e7b0c9b5e2f",
                    "product_id": 22,
                    "shop_id": 2,
                    "timestamp": "2024-07-10T06:15:42.000Z"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "date_ranges": {
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2024-07-08",
                    "key": 1720396800000,
                    "doc_count": 6
                },
                {
                    "key_as_string": "2024-07-16",
                    "key": 1721088000000,
                    "doc_count": 7
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

Expected: Starts from 2024-07-10


Can you clarify what you mean by "I still get the date_histogram not in the range."? Perhaps the example of the output of what you get vs what you expect would help? 2) What is your mapping for timestamp? 3) Can your records contain multiple timestamps per record?


@imotov Thanks for reaching out .
1- Post edited. I have attached the response retrieved from the call.
2- timestamp with type date, format date_optional_time||epoch_millis.
3- No, only one single timestamp.

First of all, I think the following sentence in Elasticsearch documentation doesn't capture what's actually going one and might have confused you.

With extended_bounds setting, you now can "force" the histogram
aggregation to start building buckets on a specific min value and also
keep on building buckets up to a max value (even if there are no
documents anymore).

You cannot force to build buckets on a specific value, you can only force building empty buckets before and after your last available document, but the bucket will start on values specified by the fixed_interval regardless of what you specify in extended_bounds. So, if the fixed interval is 8d it will only create buckets every 8 days since Jan 1, 1970.
2024-07-08 is 19,912th day after Jan 1, 1970 and 19,912 is divisible by 8 so this is why bucket starts on that date and not on 2024-07-10. To move bucket to 2024-07-10 you need to add 2d offset to date histogram. So, in your case the query should look like this:
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "timestamp": {
                            "gt": "2024-07-10T00:00:00",
                            "lt": "2024-07-22T23:59:59"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "date_ranges": {
            "date_histogram": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "fixed_interval": "8d",
                "format":"yyyy-MM-dd",
                "offset": "2d"
            }
        }
    }
}

You might also want to take a look at using hard_bounds instead of query to limit buckets that are getting created.

I needed the information about the starting count of buckets because I have a requirement where the fixed interval is configured dynamically from the server. Without the start date information, I was struggling with how to handle the offset. Maybe the official documentation should include this as well.
I really appreciate your assistance.
